# Outbound E-Mails not delivered

Tags: linux, postfix

I configured my Postfix server to use SQL Virtual Hosts and smtps. I can log in on either imap and smtp, but cannot send mails to any outbound mail server anymore when logging in via smtp. I get an `Undelivered Mail` notice back from my server. I don't get what I'm missing, does it have something to do with my `smtp_relay_restrictions`?

main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
#mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

# Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
        mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
```

master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

**Update**

Sorry, I should have read more carefully, the mail gets bounced by gmail. What exactly am I missing? My reverse host entry is correct. When I use rainloop on my server, also configured with smtps, it works fine. But thunderbird and my android mail app fail.

mail.log

```
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user@example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=87.106.145.99, mpid=3549, TLS, session=<aRH+Vt5zcZTVk6ae>
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/smtps/smtpd[3504]: 3602F28C9F: client=unknown[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=user@example.com
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/cleanup[3550]: 3602F28C9F: message-id=<>
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/qmgr[2045]: 3602F28C9F: from=<user@example.com>, size=507, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/smtps/smtpd[3504]: disconnect from unknown[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 commands=5
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/smtp[3553]: 3602F28C9F: to=<somebody@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]:25, delay=0.73, delays=0.34/0.02/0.14/0.23, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b] said: 550-5.7.1 This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass 550-5.7.1 authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.1 message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.1 information. b186-v6si7351796wmd.211 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/cleanup[3550]: E576B28CA2: message-id=<20180820140105.E576B28CA2@example.com>
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/bounce[3554]: 3602F28C9F: sender non-delivery notification: E576B28CA2
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/qmgr[2045]: E576B28CA2: from=<>, size=3029, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/qmgr[2045]: 3602F28C9F: removed
Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 dovecot: lmtp(3556): Connect from local
Aug 20 16:01:06 s20698923 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com): RLxFO6HJelvkDQAA7uhc5A: msgid=<20180820140105.E576B28CA2@example.com>: saved mail to INBOX
```

This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass 550-5.7.1 authentication checks.

Comment: The content of the `Undelivered Mail` notice would be interesting. As well as the relevant entries from your mail.log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting log event is this one:

> Aug 20 16:01:05 s20698923 postfix/smtp[3553]: 3602F28C9F:
>   to=somebody@gmail.com,
>   relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]:25,
>   delay=0.73, delays=0.34/0.02/0.14/0.23, dsn=5.7.1,
>   status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b] said:
>   550-5.7.1 This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass
>   550-5.7.1 authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the
>   550-5.7.1 message has been blocked. Please visit
>   550-5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more
>   550 5.7.1 information. b186-v6si7351796wmd.211 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))

which shows me two interesting things:

- `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]` you may not have been aware, but you're sending over IPv6.
- and the link to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication which in summary instructs you to set up DKIM, DMARC and SPF for your sender domain.

And I don't see an obvious reference to something like an OpenDKIM milter in your postfix configuration.

Frequently people have only configured a proper PTR reverse DNS record for their IPv4 addresses and not the IPv6 addresses they use, and similarly those IPv6 addresses  are not included in their SPF record.

You will need to configure both reverse DNS for all IPv4  and IPv6 addresses your mail server uses. And SPF, DNARC and DKIM for all domains hosted on your mailserver.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I fixed the SPF record first, and after configuring OpenDKIM everything works just fine.